# Cloudflare module worker env is not defined

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I created env variable for cloudflare module worker using web interface.

[image]

I'm using cloudflare dashboard to edit my worker module script. Here's the content of it.

```js
export default {
  async fetch(request) {
    return new Response(env.MY_ENV)
  }
};
```

But I get `env` is not defined.
I also tried to access it using `console.log(MY_ENV)`, but it produces the same error: `MY_ENV` is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`env` is a parameter to `fetch`, but you haven't declared it. Try declaring `fetch` like this:

```
  async fetch(request, env, ctx) {
```